# Tenho 2 source packages no mesmo projeto do netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Pergunta rápida

Tenho um projeto no meu netbeans com 2 source packages sem motivo aparente.
todos os meus projetos tem 1 source package. eles aparentam ser clonados porque se adiciono ou removo alguma coisa numa source package, a outra também vai sofrer a mesma alteração. Agradecia qualquer ajuda a saber porque que tenho 2 e como remover uma sem remover o codigo todo porque se remover uma, removo a outra também
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja se na pasta do projeto(`NetBeans Projects/<nome doseu projeto>/src`) os pacotes foram duplicados tambem. Se não, creio que basta apagar o projeto(sem apagar os arquivos) e criar um novo usando código ja existente.